# How to externally force a running application to perform basic tasks?

Tags: python, windows

I need to develop a code that causes a currently open application (running in the background) to perform basic tasks when a certain condition is met.

Let me explain through a random example…

Imagine I am working on a Microsoft word document and I want it to print exactly every 10 minutes automatically, i.e. without having to physically click the print button.  What options do I have to implement something like this?  Obviously gaining access to the MS word source code is an option, but is their an easier way…perhaps using a python script?

Thanks,

David

Comment: There is no general answer to this - it depends.  Some apps will have APIs to allow this, some will not.

Comment: Consider adding a Windows tag, as this is purely Windows programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Office products, as well as Internet Explorer and some other programs expose a Component Object Model (COM) interface.  You can find more detail about COM and how it applies to Python [here](http://oreilly.com/catalog/pythonwin32/chapter/ch12.html) (including examples).  They often expose every action you could do manually in the applications, but are aimed at automation and artificial input.

For a more generic application, you could work with sending messages.  There's a Windows function called 'postmessage', and another called 'sendmessage' which have several wrappers in Python.

By the way, the MS Word source code is *not* freely available.